# Creating dynamic javascript variable where both left and right side are dynamic

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create a dynamic javascript variable and assign it with a value which is going to be minified.

Something like

```
 var result = "res123";
 self.result = ko.observable();
 self.result(response);
```

So at the end i want a variable like `self.res123` whose value is response.

Tried

```
eval("self."+result+"= ko.observable()");
```

But then here my javascript is being minified so then i get a error telling `ko` is not defined.

I am then using this variable with knockout so in my html i have something like

```
<div data-bind="with: res123" class="oj-flex">
```

It would help if someone can suggest me any way to get through this.

Thanks in advance,
Roopa

Comment: There is no reason to ever use `eval()`. You are doing something wrong. Explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

`self['myname'] = myvalue;`

You can even do this for global variables (although this can be a very bad idea):

`window['myname'] = myvalue;`

So, for your specific question:

`self[result] = ko.observable();`

Comment: Thanks nerestaren... Did not occur to me that self.result can be used as self[result] ...